# Angularjs $q is Not Returning Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to call service method in Angularjs. The service method is called alright, however IT DOES not return any value to the function that called it in the controller.

I will be glad if anyone can help me. This is my Code bellow.

```
  logosStreams.factory("processPaypal", ['$http', '$timeout', '$q',   '$state',function($http, $timeout, $q, $state){
  var transCall = {};
  var transcallPromise2 = $q.defer();   

  return {

    onSuccesfulPayment: function(payment) {
      console.log("payment success: " + JSON.stringify(payment, null, 4));
 transcallPromise2.resolve(payment);
    },
    onAuthorizationCallback: function(authorization) {
      console.log("authorization: " + JSON.stringify(authorization, null, 4));
      //return authorization;
    },
    createPayment: function(data) {
      // for simplicity use predefined amount
      var paymentDetails = new PayPalPaymentDetails("0", "0", "0");
      var payment = new PayPalPayment(data.amt, "USD", data.name, "Sale",
        paymentDetails);
      return payment;
    },

    buyInFutureBtn : function(e) {
        // future payment
        PayPalMobile.renderFuturePaymentUI(this.onAuthorizationCallback, this.onUserCanceled);
    },

    profileSharingBtn : function(e) {
        // profile sharing
        PayPalMobile.renderProfileSharingUI(["profile", "email", "phone","address", "futurepayments", "paypalattributes"],
         this.onAuthorizationCallback, this.onUserCanceled);
    },

    buyNowBtn : function(data) {

        // single payment
        PayPalMobile.renderSinglePaymentUI(this.createPayment(data), this.onSuccesfulPayment, this.onUserCanceled);
        return transcallPromise2.promise;

    },

    onPrepareRender: function() {

    },

    onUserCanceled: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
              transcallPromise2.reject(result);

    }

}

}])
```

Inside the controller call the buyNowBtn methond

```
  processPaypal.buyNowBtn($scope.MMParams).then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
  })
```

Comment: Are you sure that the method isn't returning a promise? What happens if you do `console.log(processPaypal.buyNowBtn($scope.MMParams))`?

It could be that the promise is rejected or that it's not being resolved.

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: @CharanCherry Yes sometimes I get: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Comment: @ppham27 this log  "console.log("payment success: " + JSON.stringify(payment, null, 4));" on the success method shows result but i dont know why i dont get it in the controller

Comment: @DavidAddoteye that means the returned value is not a promise or nothing is returning

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reason that it does not return value is that your promise is not resolved. Your promise will only be resolved when you call onSuccessfulPayment().
Can you also put the code where your onSuccessfulPayment() function is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You have returned the promise object on the `buyNow` function execution...try to return the promise as part of the returned object where you have returned all the function hookups.

Comment: Please can you be a bit practical with an example. I am not getting your answer well, thanks